# How do I display the sum of multiple properties in Ractive

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ractivejs

I am using [RactiveJS](http://www.ractivejs.org/) for my templates. I have some nested data like this:

```
var view = new Ractive({
    data: {
        items: [
            { size: 1 }
            { size: 3 }
            { size: 4 }
        ]
    }
});
```

How can I display the *sum* of item sizes in my template? This depends on the size of each individual item but also on the items array (e.g. items are added/removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pembeci/mfxx5prh/) which achieves what you want by using Ractive's [computed properties](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/computed-properties). Would you consider this denormalization of data?

```
    computed: {
       sum: function () { 
           var items = this.get( 'items' ); 
           return items.reduce(function(prev, current) {
             return prev + current.size;
           }, 0)
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track the sum using an observer. This has the advantage of not having to reiterate the entire array each time a value changes. (see http://jsfiddle.net/tL8ofLtj/):

```
oninit: function () {
    this.observe('items.*.size', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        this.add('sum', (newValue||0) - (oldValue||0) );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but it's not optimal because it denormalizes data in the view.

```
var view = new Ractive({
    data: {
        items: [
            { size: 1 }
            { size: 3 }
            { size: 4 }
        ],
        sum: 0
    },
    oninit: function () {
        this.observe('items items.*.size', function () {
            this.set('sum', _.reduce(this.get('items'), function (memo, item) {
                return memo + item.size;
            }, 0));
        });
    }
});
```

And then in the template I can just use `{{sum}}`

Comment: With that approach the observer will fire `n + 1` times on initial render, meaning in your example it will calculate 4 times even though data hasn't changed.